# Windows Security Pops up behind IE on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Our Windows 10 users are trying to log into a website via ADFS. The Windows Security prompt comes up **behind** the browser where users are unlikely to notice it. Is there a way to get this prompt to appear in front of the browser like it does in Windows 7?

```
Windows 10 version is 1709 Build 16299.248 
IE 11 Version is 11.248.16299.0
```

Comment: "Windows 10" is not precise enough... there are new releases of Windows 10 on a regular basis... which build of Windows 10 ? And which browser?  If you are not using the latest Win10 version, try to upgrade and to install all the available updates

Comment: @Swisstone Thanks, I've updated the question with the info. We are using the latest version.